# CSS Line Through not behaving the way I want it too

Tags: html, css

Ok i have a simple question maybe i am missing something stupid here but I have this little block of html

```
<div class="span2">
  <span class="price flRight salePrice">$11.25 <span>$4.99</span></span>
</div>
```

With this CSS

```
.span2 .salePrice{text-decoration:line-through;}
.span2 .salePrice span{color:#cd202c;font-weight:bold;margin-left:5px;text-decoration: none !important;display: block;}
```

But why is the line through on the second span I added important and figured it would be overwritten but it isnt. Why is this not taking?

I have a simple fiddle set up incase it helps http://jsfiddle.net/XJwns/

I am sure i am overlooking something stupid here but please point me to my mistake

Comment: I appreciate everyones quick responses i was having a brain fart moment and got it resolved if i could mark them all as correct i would!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't "cancel" the line-through coming from the parent element. You can, of course, separate them into two siblings spans.

HTML

```
<div class="span2">
    <span class="price flRight salePrice">$11.25</span> <span class="other">$4.99</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.span2 .salePrice{text-decoration:line-through;}
.span2 .other{color:#cd202c;font-weight:bold;margin-left:5px;text-decoration: none !important;display: block;}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/XJwns/1/

Comment: I think i have been looking at code for entirely too long today thanks i knew it was something stupid! Appreciate you pointing it out! I will accept the answer once SO allows me too

Comment: Don't worry, it happens to everybody. You should always to what somes naturally to you semantic-wise - you'll have no problem writing proper CSS then.

Answer (score 3):

Your CSS is telling it to put a line through `.salePrice`, which is what it is doing, child `<span>` and all.

The more "standard" way of doing this is:

```
<span class="price flRight salePrice"><del>$11.25</del> <ins>$4.99</ins></span>
```

You can then style the old and new prices independently.

Comment: It's more semantic with `del` and `ins` elements to indicate the old and new values.

Comment: Actually, the “standard” (HTML5 CR) suggests the `s` element for contexts like this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-s-element

Answer (score 1):

It's because your span's are nested, the outer strikethru overlays your inner span.  Unnest them and apply styles separately, so you don't have to use !important:

```
<div class="span2">
  <span class="price flRight">$11.25</span><span class="salePrice">$4.99</span>
</div>

.span2 .price{text-decoration:line-through;}
.span2 .salePrice {color:#cd202c;font-weight:bold;margin-left:5px;display: block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UBsm8/1/

Answer (score 0):

if you set nested child as inline-block, text-decoration is applied because layout is triggered somehow.
http://jsfiddle.net/XJwns/4/

to have this inline-box to slide under text, you need parent to have a reduced width, this is more like a trick.

```
.span2 .salePrice {
    text-decoration:line-through;
}
.span2 .salePrice span {
    color:#cd202c;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-left:5px;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    display:inline-block;
}
.salePrice {
    display:inline-block;
    width:1em;/* will force to wrap words, boxes in lines */
}
```